# Looking for filetypes in multiple folders

Tags: bash

I am making a bash script that converts all .webp files into .png files using ffmpeg. But it only works for the directory that it is in. It would be great to be able to place the script in a /home/username folder and let it scan all folders for webp files. here is what i have written so far:

```
for i in *.webp;do ffmpeg -i "$i" "$i.png" ;done 
rm *webp 
for i in *.webp.png 
do
mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/.webp//'`" 
done
```

Comment: When you mean all-folders -- all folders where? Under `/home/username`? Surely you don't want to scan everything under `/`? Also, you don't need `sed`, just `mv "$i" "${i%.webp*}.png"`

Comment: you can use `find` command to get file names and then start the loop. `find . name "*.webp"`